# Optional Types With Parse and Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, option-type

```
if  var findPublisher:PFQuery = PFUser.query(){
    findPublisher.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:quote.objectForKey("publisher").objectId)//error here
    }
```

I am getting an error Value of any optional type 'Any Object'? not unwrapped. I don't know what i have done incorrectly. I am a beginner so please bear with me:)

Comment: Are you trying to use the current logged in user in Parse, or any user out of the database?

Comment: current user logged in Parse

Answer (score 0):

This is really a place where you would give each quote a pointer to a user object, and then you could just get the publisher of the quote without an extra query.  But if you want to do it this way, you would do:

```
let query = PFUser.query()!
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: (quote["publisher"] as! String)) // You can unwrap it as long as you are sure that quote is not nil, and the publisher is set.
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (user: PFObject?, error: NSError?) in 
  // check for errors and use the object
})
```

This way of doing it also creates Parse [security issues](http://blog.parse.com/learn/secure-your-app-one-class-at-a-time/), as anyone with your app's ID and key can get a full user list.

Answer (score 0):

```
let findPublisher = PFUser.query()!
    findPublisher.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: (quote["publisher"] as! String))
        findPublisher.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in

            if error == nil{
                let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser//error here
                cell.publisherLabel.text = user.username
        }
    }
```

I end up getting an error that says that AnyObject is not convertible to NSArray?

Comment: Use "getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock." like in my example.   You can do that because only one user will have each ID.  Also, this should be a comment on my example and not a separate answer.